# Duplicated results in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck with my SQL code, can anyone help me with this?

Table MUser

```sql
   | MUser_USER_NUMBER | MUser_USER_NAME |
   ---------------------------------------
   |        1          |     User1       |
```

Table MPassport

```sql
   | MPassport_USER_NUMBER| MPassport_NUMBER  | MPassport_EXPIRE_DATE |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1             |     12345678      |     2021-01-28        |
```

Table MCar

```sql
   | MCar_USER_NUMBER  | MCar_PLATE  | MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1          |  Plate 1    |      2020-12-07         |         2020-12-08         |         2021-07-01         | 
   |        1          |  Plate 2    |      2021-03-01         |         2021-03-02         |         2021-01-01         |
```

Table MDrive

```sql
   | MDrive_USER_NUMBER| MDrive_NUMBER  | MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1          |    12345678    |    2022-10-28      |
```

Used Query

```sql
SELECT MUser.MUser_USER_NUMBER As MUser_USER_NUMBER      
      ,MUser.MUser_USER_NAME AS MUser_USER_NAME       
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(Mpassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)      
          FROM MPassPort          
         WHERE MPassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MPassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MPassport.Mpassport_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE                
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)           
          FROM MDrive          
         WHERE MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MDrive.MDrive_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE  
      ,MCar.MCar_PLATE AS MCar_PLATE      
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)          
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE       
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)           
          FROM MCar         
         WHERE MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE       
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)            
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE   
  FROM (((MUser    
  LEFT JOIN MPassport On MUser.MUser_USER_NUMBER = MPassport.Mpassport_USER_NUMBER)                         
  LEFT JOIN MDrive On  MUser_USER_NUMBER = MDrive.MDrive_USER_NUMBER)               
  LEFT JOIN MCar On  MUser_USER_NUMBER = MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER)  
 WHERE (SELECT Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MPassPort          
         WHERE Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND Mpassport_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'
    OR (SELECT MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MDrive          
         WHERE MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MDrive_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'     
    OR (SELECT MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'     
    OR (SELECT MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'     
    OR (SELECT MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'
```

Query Result

```sql
   | MCar_USER_NUMBER  | MUser_USER_NAME  | MPassport_EXPIRE_DATE | MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_PLATE  | MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1          |      User1       |       2021-01-28      |                    |  Plate 1    |      2020-12-07         |         2020-12-08         |         2021-01-01         | 
   |        1          |      User1       |       2021-01-28      |                    |  Plate 2    |      2020-12-07         |         2020-12-08         |         2021-01-01         |
```

Expected result

```sql
   | MCar_USER_NUMBER  | MUser_USER_NAME  | MPassport_EXPIRE_DATE | MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_PLATE  | MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1          |      User1       |       2021-01-28      |                    |  Plate 1    |      2020-12-07         |         2020-12-08         |                            | 
   |        1          |      User1       |       2021-01-28      |                    |  Plate 2    |                         |                            |         2021-01-01         |
```

This system I'm building is to show the documents expiring in the before the date on the query.

This query is part of a larger query, but I'm stuck with this part, in the start of my project, the user can register only one car, but now I'm changing the project to accept any numbers of cars.

The query is returning duplicated data, and I'm stuck with this code.

I Edited the original question to make more easy to understand, I'm a new to coding so, need to learn a lot, sorry if is a easy question, but for me it's not.

The part of the code with the date 1900-01-01 is because when the user add the data on the system, it is the default data, so i need to exclude the default data from the result.

Thank you for all the time used to help me.

---

### Edit added sql Data

DB

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [Teste]
GO

USE Teste
GO

CREATE TABLE MUser (
    MUser_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MUser_USER_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    MUser_USER_NAME nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MUser_USER_NUMBER PRIMARY KEY (MUser_USER_NUMBER),
);

    INSERT MUser (
               MUser_USER_NUMBER
              ,MUser_USER_NAME
          ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'User1'
           )
           
CREATE TABLE MCar (
    MCar_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MCar_USER_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    MCar_PLATE nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE date NULL,
    MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE  date NULL,
    MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MCar_PLATE PRIMARY KEY (MCar_PLATE),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MCar_USER_NUMBER FOREIGN KEY (MCar_USER_NUMBER) REFERENCES MUser(MUser_USER_NUMBER)
);

    INSERT MCar (
               MCar_USER_NUMBER
              ,MCar_PLATE
              ,MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE
              ,MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE
              ,MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE
           ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'Plate1'
              ,N'2020-12-07'
              ,N'2020-12-08'
              ,N'2021-07-01'
           )
           
    INSERT MCar (
               MCar_USER_NUMBER
              ,MCar_PLATE
              ,MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE
              ,MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE
              ,MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE
           ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'Plate2'
              ,N'2021-03-01'
              ,N'2021-03-02'
              ,N'2021-01-01'
           )
           
CREATE TABLE Mpassport (
    Mpassport_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Mpassport_USER_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Mpassport_NUMBER nvarchar(50) NULL,
    Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Mpassport_USER_NUMBER PRIMARY KEY (Mpassport_USER_NUMBER),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Mpassport_USER_NUMBER FOREIGN KEY (Mpassport_USER_NUMBER) REFERENCES MUser(MUser_USER_NUMBER)
);

    INSERT Mpassport (
               Mpassport_USER_NUMBER
              ,Mpassport_NUMBER
              ,Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE
           ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'12345678'
              ,N'2021-01-28'
           )
           
CREATE TABLE MDrive (
    MDrive_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MDrive_USER_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    MDrive_NUMBER nvarchar(50) NULL,
    MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MDrive_USER_NUMBER PRIMARY KEY (MDrive_USER_NUMBER),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MDrive_USER_NUMBER FOREIGN KEY (MDrive_USER_NUMBER) REFERENCES MUser(MUser_USER_NUMBER)
);

    INSERT MDrive (
               MDrive_USER_NUMBER
              ,MDrive_NUMBER
              ,MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE
           ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'12345678'
              ,N'2022-10-28'
           )
```

---

### Edit added info about the system

The system will be as follows:
※ only part of the system

A user registers the expiration data of the documents

MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE = Driver's license

MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE = Car document

MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE = Mandatory car insurance

MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE = Car third party insurance

Other than that there are other documents, I just put this one so it doesn't get too long.

In the driver's license part it would be only one, but in the car part, the user could have more than one.

What I'm trying to do would be to log in to the system to activate this code that would look at the documents that will expire between today and a specific date for the document, in the example I put about 3 months ahead.

In the car part, it may happen that one of the data is not imputed, as it would be control of the office, and the employee has not yet delivered the documents, so I put the clause> 1900-01-01, because the default date in the DB would be That.
For the system to ignore those cars that are without the correct data.

The date <2021/02/16 (3 months from the date of login to the system) would be the maximum you would look for, to notify the employee that the document would expire on that date, to have time for the person to renew.

---

### Edit

I put my sql code online if anyone can look, thank you

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff9125/1

Comment: Please show us the result that you want. It is unclear what the purpose of your query is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  MUser.MUser_USER_NUMBER,
  MUser.MUser_USER_NAME,    
  Mpassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE,
  MCar.MCar_PLATE,
  CASE WHEN 
    MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16' AND 
    MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
      THEN MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE 
  END As MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE,
  CASE WHEN
    MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16' AND
    MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'
      THEN MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE
  END As MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE,
  CASE WHEN 
    MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16' AND
    MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'
      THEN MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE
  END As MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE   
FROM MUser    
LEFT JOIN MPassport 
  On 
    MPassport.Mpassport_USER_NUMBER = MUser.MUser_USER_NUMBER AND
    MPassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16' AND 
    MPassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'    
LEFT JOIN MDrive 
  On
    MDrive.MDrive_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER AND
    MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16' AND
    MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'
LEFT JOIN MCar 
  On
    MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER AND
    ( (MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16' AND
       MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01') 
     OR
      (MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16' AND
       MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01') 
     OR
      (MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16' AND 
       MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01') )
WHERE
  Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL OR
  MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL OR
  MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL OR
  MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL OR
  MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, when answering a question, add also an explanation of what your code does and why you think it's a good fit to question the answer.

Comment: Thanks Worked, now i will just analyze your code to understand what i did wrong in the first. thank you very much.

Comment: I have voted in your answer, but because I'm new the vote not count. But really thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what the subqueries are for. It looks like you just want a `join`:

```
select u.u.muser_user_number, m.muser_user_name, c.mcar_shaken_expire_date
from mcar c
inner join muser u on u.muser_user_number = c.mcar_user_number
```

I am unclear on the behavior you want when a car has expire date in year 1900. If you want to filter out such rows, just add a `where` clause to the query:

```
where c.mcar_shaken_expire_date > '19000101'
```

Comment: in the result i want to show only the cars that have shaken expiring from one date to another date, not all listed cars, the system will alert the user that the shaken will expire soon, so please renew. Sorry if is a little difficult to understand, I'm new to coding, still need to learn a lot, and thank you for your time.

Comment: I am addapting your answer, and i think i can get to work. SELECT U.MUser_USER_NUMBER 
      ,U.MUser_USER_NAME
      ,U.MUser_USER_NAME_EN
      ,C.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE
  FROM MCAR C                           
  INNER JOIN MUser U On  U.MUser_USER_NUMBER = C.MCar_USER_NUMBER 
  WHERE C.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'
    AND C.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'

Comment: @KristianFrancischini: yes, adding another `where` condition seems like the right way to go here.

Comment: I updated the code and info in the main post, if the user has only one car registered it's ok, but if register 2 cars the date will result in duplicated. Can you look the code and infos again? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the logic in your edit, you want the rows with the minimum shaken date:

```
select . . .  -- whatever columns you want
from muser u join
     (select c.*,
             min(MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE) as min_MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE
      from mcar c
     ) c
     on u.muser_user_number = c.muser_user_number
where date = min_MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE;
```

Comment: didn't work too, thank you, i updated the code and info for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use select Distinct
and also include MCar_PLATE in the select list.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  MUser.MUser_USER_NUMBER As MUser_USER_NUMBER  
                   , MUser.MUser_USER_NAME AS MUser_USER_NAME
                   , MCar.MCar_PLATE   
                   , MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE
FROM MCar      
LEFT JOIN MUser On  MUser_USER_NUMBER = MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER     
WHERE MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE between '1900/01/01' AND '2021/02/16'
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, i have edited my question again with some new info's, can you help me?

Comment: In your Edit 2: instead of: OR MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE between '1900/01/01' AND '2021/02/16' you might want to use this: AND MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE ISNULL

Comment: Sorry the NULL is because the date are after the between dates. not the database is null (result not found between dates). edited the null to empty.

Answer (score 0):

... *i want to show only the cars that have shaken expiring from one date to another date, not all listed cars,* ...

Try

```
-- code #1
SELECT C.MCar_PLATE, C.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE, 
       U.MUser_USER_NUMBER, U.MUser_USER_NAME
  from MCar as C
       inner join MUser as U on U.MUser_USER_NUMBER = C.MCar_USER_NUMBER
  where C.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE < '20210216'  
        and C.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE > '19000101';
```

Comment: I updated the code and info in the main post, if the user has only one car registered it's ok, but if register 2 cars the date will result in duplicated. thank you